# iOS - CoreData - TableViewController - NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: ios, core-data, uitableview

I created a storyboard with a `UITableViewController`, then added a Core Data entity. The application at this point built and run without errors, but the `UITableViewController` was showing no data.

I deleted the TVC and rebuilt in StoryBoard, but ever since I'm getting an error when I run the application and try to open the TVC:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a
>   legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name
>   'Attractions''

With a bit of research,  realize that this is due to my `managedObjectContext` being empty, but for the life of me I cannot figure out WHY it's empty.

In the TVC header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Attractions.h"
#import "AttractionListViewCell.h"
#import "ApplicationNameAppDelegate.h"

@interface AttractionListViewController : UITableViewController
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
    NSMutableArray *AttractionsArray;    
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *AttractionsArray;

- (void) fetchrecords;

@end
```

In the TVC model file:

```
ApplicationNameAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSLog(managedObjectContext);
// Create connection to the DB via Context
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Attractions" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
```

In the *ApplicationNameAppDelegate.h* file:

```
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (void)saveContext;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;
```

Any help or insight you could provide would be much appreciated.

EDIT - Added AppDelegate info:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AttractionListViewController.h"
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class AttractionListViewController;

@interface AppNameAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) AttractionListViewController *viewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (void)saveContext;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;

@end
```

Comment: Use this `NSLog(@"%@", managedObjectContext);` instead of `NSLog(managedObjectContext);` ans say what you see in the console. Then, post the implementation of Core Data stack within your `AppDelegate`.

Comment: Here's the log '2012-11-05 08:27:13.304 [9872:11603] (null)'

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
```

You are declaring a local managedObjectContext and assigning it rather than what you should do:

```
managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
```

which will use the TVC's iVar

Comment: I'm surprised that LLVM didn't throw up a warning about the local variable shadowing a global variable, which usually catches this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Abizem. I made the change, but still have the exact same issue.

Comment: Which line of code is throwing the error? Do you have an Entity called Attractions? Is your FetchedResultsController set up properly?

Comment: It's this line of code 'NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Attractions" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]; ' and yes, the entity Attractions is set up.

Answer (score 0):

So I found what the issue was. I hadn't copied over all the classes from the AppDelegate in the xcode generated example, so the classes that defined the managedObject and persistent store etc weren't there.

Answer (score -1):

In your View Controller implementation file, right under this bit of code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
```

add this bit of code:

```
id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; self.managedObjectContext = [delegate managedObjectContext];
```